# iPad MPMoviePlayerController full screen rotation move all views

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a problem with rotations in full screen mode in a MPMoviePlayerController: When I rotate the iPad in full screen mode the views behind the movie player rotate too, but there isn't a status bar and all moves 20 px up.

If I show the controllers and the status bar before rotate (pushing the screen) all works fine. Instance of that, I suppose the problem is caused because there isn't status bar durning the rotation.

Someone can help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolve the problem using a MPMoviePlayerViewController instead a MPMoviePlayerController.

Durning the full screen rotation the status bar doesn't disappear and all works fine :)